# How to move my border-top to the very top of the page?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make an hover effects on my nav bar, I want to have a line on top of the li where your cursor is.

I've given the li a `border-top` property but i need the line to be at the very top of the page not directly on top of the li.

```css
#liste li:hover{
    border-top: 3px solid;
    color: #5CABD1;
}
```

I already know the problem is the border top property but i dont know others way to put a line on top of my li. Here is a photo of my nav bar and the current border-top effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is that you're assigning the hover behavior to the list item and not the link itself. If the container link extends all the way to the top line, it should overlap and display properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<style>
 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 li {
  float: left;
 }

 li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 8px;
 background-color: #dddddd;
 text-decoration:none
}
li a:hover:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  border-top:2px solid red;
  width:40px;
  height:1px;
}
</style>
```

You can use the pseudo element to do it . Here is a demo that works on hover 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lnso4u6z/3/